# Can I calculate a date using a date plus 53 days, minus any Sundays

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a formula tha I can place in Cell L3 that results in a date by comparing the date in cell E7, adding 53 total days to that date, excluding any Sundays within that period.  The resulting date would be e. g.. (E7) 3/4/2014 plus 53 days not counting any Sundays in its way and givcing me that forward date in cell L3.

I would really appreciate any help on this please :-)

Comment: @Bigbio2002 But won't there sometimes be a different number of Sundays included within the range? For example, if your initial date is on a Monday, it will have one less Sunday included compared to if it were a Saturday.

Comment: It's a work in progress... This is a tough problem.

Comment: Just to confirm - you want to add MORE than 53 actual days because some of them are Sundays? Or add LESS than 53 actual days because some of them are Sundays?

Comment: @Shevek   It is correct that I actually want to add "more" than 53 days because some of them are Sundays

Comment: @Bigbio2002  There will a different number of Sundays based on the date that is provided so I need something that can actually see the current calendar and account for them

Comment: @Raystafarian  unfortuantely I am really just stuck at the beginning.  I get to =today +53 in my head and can't figure out how to accommodate for the Sundays on the calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula can be adapted for any number of days (53 could be replaced with another number or a cell reference):

```
=E7+53+ROUNDDOWN(53/7,0)+IF((MOD(53,7)+WEEKDAY(E7,2))>6,1,0)
```

Comment: Do you mean `ROUNDDOWN(53/7,0)` instead of `ROUNDDOWN(E7/7,0)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks, fixed.  I had the components of this as cell references, and substituted incorrectly.

Comment: @bdr9  Thankyou so much for all your help between you and Madball73 it works perfectly!

Comment: @madball73  Thankyou so much for all your help between you and bdr9 it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The following formula will add 53 days not including Sundays to the date in cell E7.

```
=E7+60+IF(WEEKDAY(E7)>=4, 1, 0)
```

There will always be at least 60 days added, because there are 53 to start with, plus at least 7 Sundays. Then, if the original date was a Wednesday, Thursday, Friday or Saturday, one additional day must be added because one more Sunday is included.

Comment: This will only work for 53. What happens if you want to add any other number of days?

Comment: @Shevek Then you would have to use a different formula. I just addressed the original question.

Comment: @Shevek  Thank you so much for your help.  I believe the formula below covers my needs but again thank you so much for offering.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a VBA macro:

```
Function CalcDate(startDate, increment) As Date

    endDate = DateAdd("d", increment, Date)

    sundays = 0

    For i = startDate To endDate
        If Weekday(i) = vbSunday Then
            sundays = sundays + 1
        End If
    Next

    If sundays > 0 Then
        endDate = DateAdd("d", sundays, endDate)
    End If

    CalcDate = endDate

End Function
```

You can then call this as you would any other built in Function:

```
=CalcDate(E7,53)
```